# Cannot connect to SQL Server 2008 database engine

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to connect to a SQL Server 2008. I just installed SQL Server 2008 and Service Pack 2. I open SQL Server Management Studio and try to connect with database engine:

- ServerName: `Laura\SQLEXPRESS`
- Authentication: Windows Authentication
- User Name: `Laura\Laureta`

Click `Connect` and shows the following error:

> A network error ocurred while establishing a connection to SQL
>   server...error 26-Error locating server/instance specified

I also turned off windows firewall

Comment: Did you install the **Express** edition, or some other edition (Standard, Web, Enterprise)? Only the **Express** edition uses the `(machinename)\SQLEXRPESS` default instance name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]Check sqlserver  service if running or not

from `start menu > run> services`

Comment: You mean services.msc

Comment: Sql server is not in the list. How can I make it run if it is not there?

Comment: I checked and it is not shown there. What does this mean?

Comment: I think you should restart your PC , and check it ,

Comment: Maybe you just installed the client tools.

Comment: if you restart your PC and not shown, maybe reinstalling sql server solve this problem!

Comment: Try to download this copy of sql server   http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22973

Comment: ok i will install it again. It is taking me a lot of time just with installation :(

Comment: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for userSettings/Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.LandingPage.Properties.Settings: Could not load file or assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: I solved it by re installing visual basic. Thank you :)